# Can we solve this equation?

Tags: calculus

Can we solve this equation or just prove that the solution exists:

$$2^n = 100\log_2(n)$$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Ex%3D100*%28log_2+%28x%29%29

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution because we try to find $x$ such that

$$f(x)=\frac{\log_2(x)}{2^x}=\frac{1}{100}$$

But $f$ is continuous and $f(1)=0$ and $f(2)=\frac{1}{4}$ and $f(16)=\frac{1}{16384}$. Hence there are at least two solutions.

Comment: So we can't really have an exact solution just an approximation am I wrong ?

Comment: You are right. And the two solutions are (approximately) $1.0140975173684110663$ and $8.2500123518501601674$. Found by computer using Maxima.

Comment: An exact solution using usual functions ? it doesn't seem so, because $f^{-1}$ can't be describe using usual functions. But you can compute solutions as precise as you want (and very quickly).